# Unable to get order by increment id in observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I use `sales_order_place_after`.

This is my observer file

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();       
    echo $order->getIncrementId();
    $collection = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());
    print_r($collection->getData());
}
```

Here I am getting increment ID but don't load order object by increment id.

Comment: @QaisarSatti My question is not about not to get order id. But I can get increment id and I am not able to get order object with increment id.

Comment: you already getting the object of order `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();   `

Comment: As @QaisarSatti, you already get order object in observer. so why you need to load second-time same order by increment id?

Comment: @PrincePatel for some reason I want to load order second time by increment id. But I dont able to load order by increment id.